# Connecting to IBM MQ using topic name instead of topic string

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Sample below - The topic name is TEST_TOP. But seems like the following method is for topic string instead of topic name. Wanted to check if i can use topic name instead of topic string? Thanks!

```
    public String sendTopic()
    {
        try {
            log.info("Send message to topic");
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("TEST_TOP","TEST SEND TO TOPIC");
            log.info("Message sent to topic");
            return "SEND OK";
        } catch(JmsException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "SEND FAIL";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a way with the JMS API. Is there a reason not to use the topic string?

Comment: No, there is no JMS API that takes topic name. You will have to use topic string.